# $\int_{0}^{1}(f'(x))^2-(f'(x))^3f(x)\; dx \geq 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Is it true, that for all functions $f$ that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ :
>   $$\int_{0}^{1}(f'(x))^2-(f'(x))^3f(x)\; dx \geq 0$$

I've tried to find counterexample, but I've not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $$f(x) = 10x(x-1)^2$$

then

$$\int_0^1f'(x)^2-f'(x)^3f(x)dx = -\frac{220}{21}$$